# Installer for Apache + MySQL + PHP + my custom PHP software?

Tags: php, windows-installer

Is there an application that exists which can be customized for installing apache mysql, php + a custom application (with a database) via a wizard similar to XAMPP?

I basically want to bundle my application with a one click installer.  I'm looking for a solution that works on windows.

Comment: yes this would be for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

For Windows:
You could use [Wix](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/).  It is a free software toolset that builds Windows Installer (MSI) packages from an XML document.

**Original Answer**
For linux:
The best way to do this would be to create packages,[rpm](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm1/) or [deb](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/01/how-to-create-deb-package-ubuntu-debian.html), with dependencies for mysql and php.